# AsyncStorage in a non async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following code:

```
 _loginAsync = async () => {
    fetch('localhost:3000/login')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('my-item', responseJson.item);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

throws the error: `Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function`.

Which is the proper way to valorize the `my-item`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.then` callback isn't marked as `async`, only the outer `_loginAsync` function is.

```
 _loginAsync = async () => {
    fetch('localhost:3000/login')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(async (responseJson) => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('my-item', responseJson.item);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

That said, it seems weird to mix all of the `.then` and `await` forms here.

**Using Async/Await Only**

I think this is the most readable version. We just use async/await to await the fetch directly instead of working with its promise.

```
 _loginAsync = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('localhost:3000/login');
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('my-item', response.json().item);
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

**Using Promises Directly**

You can (pretty much) always use an async function as a normal function that returns a promise as well. So instead of `await`ing `AsyncStorage.setItem` we can just use its promise as part of our chain by returning it from `then`.

```
 _loginAsync = () => {
    fetch('localhost:3000/login')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => AsyncStorage.setItem('my-item', responseJson.item))
      .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home'))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Can I remove the "async" keyword using promises directly, right?

Comment: oh yep, definitely. fixed!

Answer (score -1):

If you have to make it work for your code, make the anonymous function for the block where `await` occurs to `async`.

```
_loginAsync = async () => {
    fetch('localhost:3000/login')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(async (responseJson) => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('my-item', responseJson.item);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

---

But I prefer this is a much better approach and looks more readable. Try this code instead.

```
_loginAsync = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('localhost:3000/login');
        const responseJson = response.json()
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('my-item', responseJson.item);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoters, can you give me hints on what's wrong with the code?